# How to check something in the list in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

How we put the condition on list data in Struts2?

i have a list which have some string like sportsmen, businessmen, employer, software-engg etc in a single td of a table.
i want to check if this list have employer string in a td then next td can display some setting option.

Comment: I am sorry I did not get your question.  If you can elaborate it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<s:iterator>` tag to iterate through the list, and use `<s:if>` tag to define condition.